# How to know the jclass to which a jobject belongs (JNI)

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I need to call the same native C method from my JNI code. This method receives a generic `jobject` object, but its behavior is different depending on the type of the object itself.

I have two `jclass` objects, named activityCls and fragmentCls (which respectively map an Activity class and a Fragment class in Java). What can I do in order to know if the given `jobject` object is of kind activityCls or fragmentCls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using `IsInstanceOf`?

> IsInstanceOf
>
> jboolean IsInstanceOf(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jclass clazz);
>
> Tests whether an object is an instance of a class.

[JNI documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html)

Comment: Yes it is. An easy question but at the end of the day I have found the point of the JNI code which made me mad and had no more strength for thinking! Thanks