# How to track which class the interface object has in JNI

Tags: java-native-interface

Suppose, we've got a `jobject interfaceObj` of some interface class. How to track back the actual class of this `jobject` abstracted by an interface? In the following code `IsInstanceOf` does not work (always ends up at `// error`). Possibly, because `jobject` is an instance of interface class, and is not recognized as an instance of its actual class?

```
jclass interfaceClass = env->GetObjectClass(interfaceObj);
jclass class1 = env->FindClass("Class1");
jclass class2 = env->FindClass("Class2");
if (env->IsInstanceOf(interfaceObj, class1))
    ...
else if (env->IsInstanceOf(interfaceObj, class2))
    ...
else
{
    // error
}
```

The actual class name is reachable through getClass().getName() of `jobject`, but is there a better way to check `interfaceObj` is an instance of particular class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know the jclass to which a jobject belongs (JNI)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049272/how-to-know-the-jclass-to-which-a-jobject-belongs-jni)

Comment: No, IsInstanceOf does not work. Possibly, because `jobject` is an instance of interface class, and is not recognized as an instance of its actual class.

Comment: Well you would need to show some actual code how that `jobject` and the classes are made then.

Comment: OK, added the code.

Comment: Leaving aside the JNI aspect of this, you shouldn't need to know. You should be using polymorphism to help you out of situations like this, not put you into them.